# SCSS styles not being shown in the Sinatra app from "Jump Start Sinatra" book

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sass

I was following along to the tutorial in the book [Jump Start Sinatra](http://www.sitepoint.com/store/jump-start-sinatra/) and I have looked over the file for typos. But for some reason the styles wont show up.

Here are the instructions

[image]

[image]

This is what I have

#### main.rb

```
require 'sass'
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?

get('/styles.css'){ scss :styles }

get '/' do
  slim :home
end

get '/about' do
    @title = "All about this website"
  slim :about
end

get '/contact' do
  slim :contact
end

not_found do
  slim :not_found
end

require 'sass'

get('/styles.css'){ scss :styles }
```

The book said to delete the old `styles.css` from the public folder, which I did (and that was previously working fine). And the book did say to included the `styles.scss` in the `views` directory. Here is my structure and **styles.css** file

[image]

Does this imply that I should also remove the reference to the CSS file that I had in the layout.slim file? This is what I have there now

#### layout.slim

```
doctype html
html lang="en"
  head
    title== @title || "Songs by Sinatra"
    meta charset="utf-8"
  body
    header
      h1 Songs by Sinatra
      == slim :nav
      section
        == yield
```

What I am missing? is it a typo? am I forgetting to do something? does the book have a gap in information that it assumes that a reader would know to do? I added the code, then ran `gem install sass` and restarted the server. So what could i possibly be missing?

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: Downvoted? Nope. Someone else did. I just pointed out you needed to add more information. Just because someone takes the time to try to help you keep your question from being closed *DOESN'T* mean they downvoted you. As a result I don't understand your attitude.

Comment: What happens when you visit the stylesheet URL (e.g. `http://localhost:9292/styles.css`)? What error does it show?

Comment: @ArmanH I got an error of `Invalid CSS after "red:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " #903;"`

Comment: That means you have a syntax error in your `styles.scss`. Comment out the offending line, and try again without it to see if SASS to CSS conversion works.

Comment: In fact, your error is on line 1: `red: #903` should be `$red: #903`. You left out the `$` in front. Fix that, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this had multiple errors. Hopefully my explanation can prompt you to improve your problem solving skills.

I did have some typographical errors in my **styles.css** file as pointed out in comments. So to test it I visited their repo on github. Then copy/pasted into my file.

Then I did notice that the author did a poor job in explaining what should be done in the layout file. So I checked his file in the repo (by the way,what is written in the book's previous chapter was not accurate). Anyways here is the layout file that worked

#### layout.slim

```
doctype html
html lang="en"
  head
    title== @title || "Songs by Sinatra"
    meta charset="utf-8"
    link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"
body
  header
    h1 Songs by Sinatra
    == slim :nav
    section
      == yield
```

What was needed was the modification to refence the **CSS** file

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"
```